# Python Series - if it is between the values of two other series (time)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe with datetime (df1). I want to know if the datetime in a 'col1' in df1 is between any of the pair of the datetime of two columns ('lowerbound' and 'upperbound') in another dataframe (df2).

For example:

```
df1 = pd.to_datetime(['2014-04-09 07:37:00','2015-04-09 07:00:00',
                     '2014-02-02 08:31:00','2014-03-02 08:22:00'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns = ['col1'])

lowerbound = pd.to_datetime(['2014-04-09 07:25:00','2014-02-02 08:30:00',
                     '2015-04-09 06:00:00','2014-03-02 08:12:00'])  
upperbound = pd.to_datetime(['2014-04-09 07:38:00','2014-04-09 07:48:00',
                     '2015-04-09 08:00:00','2014-02-02 08:33:00')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(lowerbound,columns = ['lowerbound'])    
df2['upperbound'] = upperbound
```

The result shall be [1,1,0,0] since:

- df1['col1'][0] is between df2['lowerbound'][0] & df2['lowerbound'][0]
- df1['col1'][1] is between df2['lowerbound'][2] & df2['lowerbound'][2]
- Although df1['col1'][2] is between df2['lowerbound'][1] & df2['lowerbound'][3], the index for df2['lowerbound'] and df2['lowerbound'] are not the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like results should be `[1,1,1,1]` ?

Comment: @RafaelC Not really. For example, for df1['col1'][3]: '2014-03-02 08:22:00', it is not between any pair of df2['lowerbound'][x] and df2['lowerbound'][x] for x in range 0-3.

Comment: But that is because you have *upperbound* values which are smaller than *lowerbound* values, which make no sense.

Comment: True that it doesnt make sense to have upperbound values smaller than lowerbound values. it's just an example though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`np.greater_than`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.greater_equal.html#numpy.greater_equal) and [`np.less_than`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less_equal.html#numpy.less_equal) with [`outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) and `any` in axis=1, such as:

```
import numpy as np
print ((np.greater_equal.outer(df1.col1, df2.lowerbound)
       & np.less_equal.outer(df1.col1, df2.upperbound))
       .any(1).astype(int))
```

here is gives with your data `[1 1 1 1]`

Comment: @Ben.T thanks! i think it makes perfect sense. However, i dont understand why the result i get form this solution and that from the solution by RafaelC are different..

Comment: @RafaelC do you alo have any idea why we get different results from the two solutions?

Comment: @MATTHEW in the example you gave, the solutions yield the same result. Can you provide a [mcve] where they differ?

Comment: @RafaelC, my bad - the two solutions actually give me the same answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need `apply` in this case

```
df1.col1.apply(lambda dat: ((dat>= df2.lowerbound) & (dat <= df2.upperbound)).any())
```